# Is there any way to store a Jquery element in an HTML5 data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Jquery element that I want to store in the DOM in the following way:

```
var html = '<button data-element="' + $('.some-selector') + '">Some action</button>';

$(html).appendTo('body');

console.log($('button').data('element'));
```

This yields a reference like `jQuery331040235755567121182`. Is there any way to convert that back into a normal Jquery object?

PS: I do **not** want to store it after adding the button (such as `$('button').data('element', $('.some-selector'))`)

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why not just store the selector, or keep the association in a `Map` or something?

Comment: *"I do not want to store it after adding the button (such as $('button').data('element', $('.some-selector')))*" And why not? The most *jQuery*ish way would probably be `$(html).data('element', $('.some-selector')).appendTo('body')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.  In your first line, `$('.some-selector'])` returns a jQuery Object.  By adding it to a string, the objects are converted to something like `"[object Object]"`.  I THINK what you want is something like:

```
var html = $('<button>Some action</button>').data('element', $('.some-selector'));
$(html).appendTo('body');
console.log($(html).data('element'));
```

The first line creates the button object, and adds the jQuery objects in data 'element' - not sure why you would avoid this.  The second adds it to the body.  The third line prints out the jQuery object.  One (of the many) advantages of using jQuery's `.data` is that it will avoid circular references - a plus if you are storing DOM objects within DOM objects.

Comment: you don't need to wrap `html` in `$()`, it is already a jquery object here.

Comment: That's true.  I was trying to minimally change the OP's code.  Also, to be honest, I tend to rewrap jQuery objects a lot, as they are usually buried far enough in my code to be some other type.